# Alterar valor de byte em nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary

No php para alterar o valor de determinados bytes no arquivo binário, usaria um simples replace. Como por exemplo:

```
$acc = fread($f5900xt, filesize(public_path("5900xt")));

$demoid = substr($acc, 0, $userlenght);
$demopass = substr($acc, 16, $passlenght);

$acc = str_replace($demoid, $login, $acc);
$acc = str_replace($demopass, $password, $acc);
```

Tentei algo semelhante no nodejs, mas o replace não conta as casas necessárias no arquivo.

```
var accountFileExample = fs.readFileSync('./src/fileUtils/5900xt', 'binary', { enconding: 'utf8'});
    var accountFinally;

    const demoid = accountFileExample.substring(0, loginLength);
    const demopass = accountFileExample.substring(16, passLength);
    accountFinally = accountFileExample.replace(demoid, login)
    accountFinally = accountFinally.replace(demopass, password)
    console.log(accountFileExample);
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

No JavaScript, o `replace` ocorre somente no primeiro item, porque ele por padrão usa `Expressoes Regulares`.

Para contornar isso, você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
accountFinally = accountFileExample.replace(new RegExp(demoid, 'g'), login);
accountFinally = accountFinally.replace(new RegExp(demopass, 'g'), password);
```

Comment: Legal, obrigado informação. fill funciona dessa forma também? Consegui algo como ```data.fill(login, 0, login.length);
      data.fill(password, 16, password.length);``` porém o segundo fill não funciona.